# How does Soundcloud create background gradients from album art?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect on my website and would like to know the easiest way to accomplish it.

Here's an example of what I'm referring to: https://soundcloud.com/iamtheelephante/the-magician-sunlight-elephante-remix

Comment: Have you looked into the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)? With this you could put the image on a canvas and use [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to read the individual pixel color values then somehow make a calculation to get the relevant colors and then put them into a CSS3 `linear-gradient`. This is one possibility.

Comment: Oh awesome, I didn't know about this. I just looked into the getImageData method and you're definitely on the right track. I'm still wondering how they identify and extract the right colors with enough contrast to produce a pleasant gradient.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sourceImage = document.getElementById('myImage');

/*
Include ColorThief - Library
https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/
*/
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var paletteArray = colorThief.getPalette(sourceImage,2); //Returns an array with 3 colors in rgb format

var container = document.getElementsByClassName('myContainer')[0];

container.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient( top left, rgb(' + paletteArray[0].join(',') + '), rgb(' + paletteArray[1].join(',') + '), rgb(' + paletteArray[2].join(',') + ') )'; //Works only in webkit browsers like Chrome or Safari
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/msrvLfb2/)